# Creating parabolas (or not)

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

I'm trying to create a dataset, and I want data that has, or does not have a parabola. So far, I've been using the quadratic equation by creating random lines $x$ (negative and positive), and random values (negative and positive) for both $a$ and $b$, and I'm getting all of the lines/curves I need.

However, I now want to try and automatically label them and therefore need to be able to create a parabola (or not) without having to manually check them. I understand how $a$ and $b$ in the quadratic equation affect the result, and I think it's the relationship between the line $x$ and the value of $b$ that will determine if there is a parabola or not, but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to control the result I get back?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Does your data set consist of ordered pairs of numbers? Are you looking for sets of points lying on a parabola? How to you use the quadratic formula to create lines rather than parabolas? It is not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I'm randomly picking numbers to create lines, and more random numbers as the parameters. For example:

$x = 1,2,...100$
$a = 50$
$b = -35$

using $a*(x^2) + (b*x) + 1$ where $x$ is every value $1:100$, I get a positive exponential line.

If $x = 40, 39, ... - 30$
$a=20$
$b=-35$

I get a parabola. 

Does that make it clearer?

Comment: If you are generating data points of the form $(x_i,y_i)$ satisfying $y=ax^2+bx+1$ (which is the equation of a parabola) then all the points will lie on that parabola so long as $a\ne0$.

Comment: Thanks John, however I'm actually trying to create the parabola using the equation - depending on the b value, sometimes the parabola is outside of the data (which is fine, I want exponential growth/decline sometimes) however I'm trying to find how to create the desired data without having to visually check if the parabola has been created. Does that make sense?